# no viable alternative at character ' ' in apex code

Tags: salesforce, apex

Here is the task in one of the tutorials of Trail head. But, after trying that out, the error "no viable alternative at character ' ' " has been occurring no matter what so ever changes were made. 
here's the code :

```html
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    List<Task> taskList= new List<Task>();
    
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        
        //Only create Follow Up Task only once when Opp StageName is to 'Closed Won' on Create
        if(Trigger.isInsert) {
            if(Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
                taskList.add(new Task(Subject = 'Follow Up Test Task', WhatId = opp.Id));
            }
        }
        
        //Only create Follow Up Task only once when Opp StageName changed to 'Closed Won' on Update
        if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
            if(Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' 
            && Opp.StageName != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName) {
                taskList.add(new Task(Subject = 'Follow Up Test Task', WhatId = opp.Id));
            }
        }       
    }

    if(taskList.size()>0) {        
        insert taskList;        
    }    
}
```

what can be the main cause for that error?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did it report a line number of where the error actually occurred?

Comment: yes, the line number was 2 and column 0 where List was used

Comment: Can you try copy of the code to notepad, save in ANSI encoding and then open the file and copy and paste the code back? It could be some kind of a non-printable character that you copied or entered unintentionally.
Happened to me when I copied sample code from powerpoint presentation.

Comment: @7'7' Your code has no issues. May be you've copy-paste it, that's why it's giving you an error. I would suggest you to open developer console and create a new trigger on `Opportunity` and then paste remaining contents. Your code probably will work.

Comment: Code compiles, do what Zlatin said..

Comment: Thanks for the support, it got resolved.